# Wordpress CPT rewrite slug subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

We have a Wordpress website based on ListingPro theme. Website has a custom post type Channel, having slug "c". A Elementor Pro template is linked to the channel page. Now we want to add links to subpages of channel, for example,

```
mysite.com/c/yourcoach/aboutus
mysite.com/c/yourcoach/packages
mysite.com/c/yourcoach/coachinginfo
mysite.com/c/yourcoach/contactus
```

There are pages aboutus, packages, coachinginfo and contactus, which should show information for a channel. For example mysite.com/c/yourcoach/aboutus should show aboutus details of yourcoach channel and mysite.com/c/teachingmantra/aboutus should show aboutus details of teachingmantra. Aboutus page will load the details through channelname query parameter i.e. yourcoach or teachingmantra. There is no mysite.com/c/yourcoach/aboutus page and need to redirect to aboutus page along with query parameter channelname.

We found following code at stackoverflow but it didn't work. Infact, we made a direct page redirect but again didn't work.

1: Add a rewrite tag

```
function channel_subpage_rewrite_tag() 
{
  add_rewrite_tag('%channelname%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'channel_subpage_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

2: Add a Rewrite Rule

```
function channel_subpage_rewrite_rule() 
{
add_rewrite_rule('^c/([^/]*)/aboutus','index.php?page_id=280990&channelname=$matches[1]','top');
}

  add_action('init', 'channel_subpage_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Please advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are pages aboutus, packages, coachinginfo and contactus, which should show information for a channel. For example mysite.com/c/yourcoach/aboutus should show aboutus details of yourcoach channel and mysite.com/c/teachingmantra/aboutus should show aboutus details of teachingmantra. Aboutus page will load the details through channelname query parameter i.e. yourcoach or teachingmantra. There is no mysite.com/c/yourcoach/aboutus page and need to redirect to aboutus page along with query parameter channelname. I hope it clarifies the problem.